# Hide or rename other iOS apps

Tags: ios

Can I make an app that would allow you to hide or disguise the other apps on your phone, if you downloaded an app that you didn't want your wife or child to know you had on your phone if she ever looked?

Can we change the icon and name to something else from our app?

Comment: I Guess you can't do this. may be in jialbreak you can do.

Comment: we can't because for that we need info.plist or main bundle or app store unique id for that particular app that we want to hide from our application and i that is not possible to access.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do this on a non-jailbroken device. Apple certainly wouldn't allow you to submit such an app to the App Store.